# Default PWM signal to Off

Tags: stm32, pwm, led-driver

I have this LED circuit based on the AL8843 chip. The default powered on state is a full blast LED until the STM32 is up and running and sends a low PWM pulse. The AL8843 is set to full power if CTRL is floating I believe. Ideally I want the LED to be off until the PWM signal is present.

Is adding a resistor to GND on the PWM line acceptable to achieve what I'm after? It works, but is it correct? Are there any side effects?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8843.pdf).

> *is adding a resistor to GND on the PWM line acceptable to achieve what
> I'm after?*

I would suggest that the 100 kΩ pull-down resistor may not be "strong" enough. Try it and see but I'd go for 10k or even lower.

Comment: Yeah - I just updated my post to reflect the AL8843 being the source of the "issue". Good call on a smaller resistor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a resistor seems like a good solution here and 100K is probably a good value as well. Additionally, the datasheet mentions adding a capacitor to the CNTRL pin to increase soft-start up time. I'm not sure how long it takes to stop floating, but if this is a brief, less that .5sec, than adding a cap may also be a viable solution.

There should also be a way to set the initial state of you uC pins. Your uC shouldn't be taking more than a few mS to get ready, the issue could be in your code.